# Why isn't this React iteration of images working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and calling Dog API. I got it to work for rendering an image, but when I tried to render multiple images, it doesn't work. For context, the API call link is https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/5 where "/5" specifies the number of images. I'm pretty sure that the state is being set because when I put console.log instead of setting the state, it's giving me the JSON with the urls to the images. I'm getting back an error message of "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/5")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({data: json}));
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.message.map((item, id) => (
          <img src={item} key={id} alt="dog" />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

`this.state.data.message` doesn't exist when the component first loads.  Instead, you've set `this.state.data` to an empty array, then later replace it with an object.  It's best to keep the types consistent.

The simplest change is probably just to set up `this.state.data.message` to be an empty array:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    data: {
      message: []
    },
  }
}
```

From there, taking note of the asynchronous nature of the AJAX operation, you might also consider implementing a "loading state" for when there are no images to display.  (Perhaps even a meaningful empty state for when the operation has *completed* and there are still no images?  An error state?  etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Check if the data has been manipulated or not. If not yet set the state by the API call then there is nothing `this.state.data.message`.

**Note that**, the `?.` sign is called [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). Optional chaining is used to check if an object has it's key or not in the deep level & also the Optional Chaining does not have the `IE` support.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.data?.message?.length > 0 && this.state.data.message.map((item, id) => (
                <img src={item} key={id} alt="dog" />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Would work only if OP is using typescript, doesn't appear so

Comment: Why would it only work only on typescript?

Comment: Thank you for the information about optional chaining. Now I'm getting an error that says "this.state.data.message.map is not a function", did I put something in wrong?

Comment: I've checked it and it's working. Did you write the `render` function exactly what have I written?

Comment: Oh yeah, it works. I had taken the "/5" out of the API call for some reason, I added it back in and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It happened because when the page initially rendered, the `data` state is just an empty array. You have to add `?` as an [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) which basically 'ignore' the error when you are accessing a property of something undefined.

Your code should be something like this

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.message?.map((item, id) => (
          <img src={item} key={id} alt="dog" />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

So when the `data` state is empty it would not render anything.
Another way to do it is to check whether the state has content with

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.message &&
         this.state.data.map((item, id) => (
          <img src={item} key={id} alt="dog" />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
```

This code will check whether the `data.message` is truthy and will render the component, otherwise it will render nothing. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)
}